# Stochastic Process: On a chessboard a single random knight performs a simple random walk

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

On a chessboard a single random knight performs a simple random walk. From any square, the knight chooses from among its permissible moves with equal probability. If the knight starts on a corner, how long, on average, will it take to return to that corner?

---

I understand the question. I know that from the corner the knight has two choices of squares. From the two squares the piece has 5 directions (for each location), etc.

The thing is, I want to create a transition matrix for this Markov Chain. But I can't think of how to do this without each square representing a separate state..which would make is 64x64 transition matrix.

I'm certain I'm over-complicating this problem but does anyone have some advice on how to move forward? If I can create the transition matrix then I can make the corner an absorbing state and I'll be golden to move forward.

Comment: I'm not sure you're overcomplicating it. However, you might simplify it a little.  The diagonal symmetry allows you to reduce the problem from 64 to 36 states.  Once you notice that the knight's square changes color with each move, though, you can model the two-move transitions only, thereby keeping to squares of the starting color.  Along with the first observation, that reduces the problem to 20 states. I would suggest first solving the problem on the 4x4 board (with 6 states) because it might help you discover further simplifications.

Comment: Interestingly, on boards of size $2n\times 2n$, the mean return time is $8(n-1)(2n-1).$

Comment: See the top answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1588958/knight-returning-to-corner-on-chessboard-average-number-of-steps
(around 168 moves)

Comment: I appreciate the responses everyone. Thank you @AlexR. I thought I had searched to double check that this wasn't asked but evidently I posted this too soon. Thank you for the link. It was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can simulate it using a big transition matrix and roll it, while observing the cumulative probability of jumping back to the corner, an absorbing state. This is a Markov traverse on a graph with 64 nodes and a lot of sides, each representing allowed move of a knight on a board.

The average is suprisingly high: 168. This many steps in average is the length of the cycle in this graph when you start in the corner.

Here's the solution in Python:

```
import numpy as np

def jump(i,j):
   "true if jump is allowed"
   ret = (abs(i) == 2 and abs(j) == 1) or (abs(i) == 1 and abs(j) == 2)
   return ret

# init state after 1st jump
s1 = np.zeros(64) # state after 1st jump

for i in range(8):
    for j in range(8):
        if jump(i,j):
            s1[i*8 + j] = 1
s1 = s1 / np.sum(s1)
# print(np.reshape(s1,(8,8)))           

p = np.zeros((64,64)) # transition matrix, where state num k = 8 * i + j

# init tx matrix
for ki in range(8):
    for kj in range(8):
        k = ki*8 + kj
        for i in range(8):
            for j in range(8):
                if jump(ki-i,kj-j):
                    p[k, i*8 + j] = 1
        p[k, :] = p[k, :] / np.sum(p[k, :])
        # print(ki,kj,np.reshape(p[k,:],(8,8)))
p[0,:] = np.zeros(64)
p[0,0] = 1
# print(0,0,np.reshape(p[0,:],(8,8)))

steps = 10000
cumps = np.zeros(steps) # cumulative probability of each cycle length

s = s1
for step in range(2,steps):
    s = np.matmul(s, p)
    cumps[step] = s[0]
#    print(step, ps[step])
ps = np.diff(cumps) # probability of a step
print("check add up to 1: ",cumps[steps-1])
print("mean steps: ",np.dot(range(1,steps),ps))

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# plt.plot(range(1,1001), ps[0:1000])
plt.plot(range(1,1001), cumps[1:1001])
plt.xlabel("cycle length")
plt.ylabel("probability")
plt.title("CDF")
plt.show()
```

[image]